# Avoid displaying 1970-01-01 when strtotime is false

Tags: php, mysql, date, format

How can I avoid displaying 1970-01-01 when the database field is empty? Since my webpage is in Europe I need to display the date like this dd.mm.YYYY using this code:

```
    <?php echo date("d.m.Y", strtotime($row['date'])); ?>
```

But where the db fields are empty I get the 1970-01-01. I understand why this is happening, but is there a way to avoid this and display a blank field on the webpage insted?

Original format of the date in the db is YYYY-mm-dd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <?php 

 if(isset($row['date']) && $row['date'] !="")
 {
     $date = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($row['date']));
 }
 else {
     $date = "";
}
 echo $date ; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Er, had to tweak your answer a little bit, but the solution was in your answer. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```
$date = empty($row['date']) ? "" : date("d.m.Y", strtotime($row['date']));
echo $date;
```